# UICollectionView not rendering cells after some time (cellForItemAtIndexPath is not being called after some time)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a problem with `UICollectionView`. The problem is that after I made my cells dynamic in height(the problem didn't occur with static height), after some time, when data change(I'm adding or replacing cells and calling `[self.collectionView reloadData];`), and the cells just stop being displayed / disappear (at start the cells are always being displayed properly). This happens randomly, sometimes earlier, sometimes later, for the same content. The scroll is present, and height of the whole thing seems to reflects the height of cells, also `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is being called, and is returning proper values(so is `numberOfItemsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`), but `cellForItemAtIndexPath` stops being called. After the content has disappeared - the UICollectionView will not display any cells no matter what data I try to display (even the initial data that was displaying with no problem). What is worth to mention is that I'm calling `[self.collectionView reloadData];` quite a lot, because I'm lazy-loading the images, and refreshing collection view after each image gets loaded.

in my UICollectionViewController I have:

```
        - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    float height = 0.0f;
    CGSize retval;
    ...
                height = [T20UploadMessageCell getImageHeight:m.upload];
                retval = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height);

    ...
            return retval;
        }
```

in T20UploadMessageCell.m

```
+(float)getImageWidth:(Upload*)upload{
    return 98.0f;
}

+(float)getImageHeight:(Upload*)upload{
    if (upload.isLoaded)
        return 42.0f + upload.height * ([T20UploadMessageCell getImageWidth:upload]/upload.width);
    else return 140.0f;
}
```

I've tried adding

```
-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}
```

in my layout, but that didn't help
I know this can happen for cells that have big height, but I don't think that is the case here, because the max height is 385, also tried limiting it, and also as I mentioned before - for the same cells this can happen or not - it's just random. Will appreciate the help with this. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am experiencing a similar bug.

Comment: was a long time a go and don't remember exactly, but I think what fixed it for me was calling my reloadData async (don't ask me why :) ):

- (void)onUploadImageLoaded:(NSNotification*)notification{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.collectionView reloadData]; 
    });
}